# How does adding n integers to a string result in subtracting the first n characters?

Tags: arrays, c, string, operators, c-strings

In trying to find out how to compare the ends of strings, a lot of answers suggest:

```
(strncmp(string1 + length_string1 - length_string2, string2, length_string2)
```

Great that it works, I understand the basic implementation of `strncmp`, but I'm having difficulty understanding how the following expression works:

```
string1 + length_string1 - length_string2
```

How is it that you're able to use the `+` operator with a `const char*` (string1) and an `int` (or `size_t`) (length_string1) inside of `strncmp` but when I compile the following

```
int n = string1 + length_string1 - length_string2;
```

I get an error? The error makes sense (can't initialize an int using a string, sure) but the ability to do this inside of `strncmp` evades me.

How is it that adding `n` value to `string1` removes the first `n` characters when used in certain functions? For example:

In experimenting with `printf("%s", s + 3);` where `const char* s = "Hello World";` it printed `lo World`, why does this occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `const char*` is a pointer, and as such, and like all the other pointers (unless they are constant), if you add a scalar to it it will increment the pointer the same number of times as the scalar provided.

`s + 3` makes it so that the pointer will be pointing to the address of 4th character, to `&s[3]` of the string, it's the equivalent of having `s = &s[3]`, after this if you print `s` with `printf` it will print all the characters from there on until it finds a nul character which what it does when you use `"%s"` specifier.

Note that the characters are not removed it's just that the pointer is ahead.

Take the code:

```c
const char *s = "Hello world!";

s += 3; //increment 3 times
printf("%s\n", s);

s -= 3; //decrement 3 times
printf("%s\n", s);
```

The output:

```
lo world!
Hello world!
```

Note that the string is still there, you can point the pointer to the beginning of the string again.

`int n = string1 + length_string1 - length_string2;` does not work because you are assigning `const char*` or `char*` to `int` and these are incompatible.

`(strncmp(string1 + length_string1 - length_string2, string2, length_string2)` works as it should because you are passing the correct arguments 2 `char*` arguments as explained in the previous paragraf.

Answer (score 1):

In C, a string is an immutable array of char, and an array is defined by a pointer to the first element and its size.

For instance doing, `char* my_string` and later on `my_string = new char[10]` will create the same object as `char[10] my_string`.

Now considering the value of a pointer `p` as a memory address, adding integer `n` to its value will translate it of `n` memory addresses, and will point to `p+n`.

Lastly the reason you can not do `int n = string1 + length_string1 - length_string2;` is because `string1 + length_string1 - length_string2` is not an `int` but a pointer of type `char*`. If you really want to interpret the value of the pointer as an integer you can use atoi (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/).

Answer (score 0):

EXAMPLE:

```
const char* s = "Hello World"
printf("%s", s + 3);
```

OUTPUT: `lo World`

EXPLANATION:

Your "printf()" example is simply printing "Hello World" ... starting from the 4th character, instead of the first.

It's not "subtracting" anything. It's just starting from a different place :)

COMPLETE EXAMPLE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  const char* s = "Hello World";
  const char a[] = "Hello World";

  printf("%s\n", s);  // "Hello World"
  printf("%s\n", s + 3);  // "lo World"

  printf("strlen(s):%ld\n", strlen(s));  // 11 character string
  printf("strlen(s+3):%ld\n", strlen(s+3));  // 8-character string

  printf("sizeof(s): %ld\n", sizeof(s));  // 8: 64-bit pointer
  printf("sizeof(a): %ld\n", sizeof(a));  // 12: char[12] (11 characters, + delimiter)

  return 0;
}
```